# useSelector not rerender component like connect in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've tried to search about for this issue but most of the topic is about mutate but it's a primitive datatype in my case and here is the example code:

```js
// ParentPage.jsx
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const selectShowFooterFlag = (state) => {
    return state.shouldShowFooter;
}

const ParentPage = () => {
    const shouldShowFooter = useSelector(selectShowFooterFlag);
    const ChildComponent = useSelector(selectChildComponent);

    return (
        <p>{String(shoudShowFooter)}</p>
        <ChildComponent shoudShowFooter={shoudShowFooter}>
    )
}
export default ParentPage;
```

```js
// ChildPage

const ChildPage = ({ shoudShowFooter }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(shouldShowFooterState(false));
        return () => {
             dispatch(shouldShowFooterState(true));
        }
    });

    return (
        <p>String(shoudShowFooter)</p>
    )
}
```

```js
// reducer
const initalState = {
    isPageFooterRequired: true,
};

export const pagesReducer: (draft, action) = produce((draft = initialState, action: DispatchAction) => {
    switch() {
        case SHOW_FOOTER:
            draft.shoudShowFooter = action.payload;
            break;

        default:
           return draft;
    }
});
```

With this example, when child component mounted, it will set `shoudShowFooter` to `false` as expected. When `ChildComponent` updated in redux store, the current ChildComponent will unmount and set the `shoudShowFooter` to `true`. I've checked that and it's correct as expected (the `selectShowFooterFlag` has been called).

But the issue is that `shoudShowFooter` changed in redux but `ParentPage` not re-render with new state so that new ChildComponent can't receive the latest data in reducer store (I've checked with the latest state data by Redux devtools).

One more interesting point is that when I switch to use connect, everything working just fine.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const selectShowFooterFlag = (state) => {
    return state.shouldShowFooter;
}

const ParentPage = () => {
    const ChildComponent = useSelector(selectChildComponent);

    return (
        <p>{String(shoudShowFooter)}</p>
        <ChildComponent shoudShowFooter={shoudShowFooter}>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
         shouldShowFooter: selectShowFooterFlag(state);
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentPage);
```

I think useSelector will give us the same behavior like connect, will re-render component when state data change. But seems like it's not in this case.

How could I make `useSelector` trigger re-render with latest data like what `connect` does? Or how could I debug this case to see why React not re-render the app?

Comment: Can you post your reducer too?

Comment: Sure @keysl. I've added my reducer for this case.

Comment: Can you show your store setup and root reducer creation? This is most likely caused by your selector functions trying to read state fields that don't exist, but to confirm that I'd need to see how the root state / root reducer are defined.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but it looks like you are missing the value in your `switch`.  It is `switch()` but it should be `switch(action.type)`.

Comment: `const ChildComponent = useSelector(selectChildComponent)` I would recommend against storing a component in Redux.  You should only store serializable data.